# Ethernet and Wifi segments on the same subnet

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

I'm using a BeagleBoneBlack with two network interfaces, eth0 and wlan0. 
eth0 is configured to use dhcp, while wlan0 has a static address. I configured hostapd to create an access point on wlan0, and I also configured a local dhcp server to serve requests on wlan0 interface. So far everything is fine.

What I would like to do now is to configure wlan0 to use dhcp to get an address of the same subnet of eth0, and also the clients connecting to the AP should get an address of such subnet.

Basically I would like the Wifi segment of the network to rely on the same dhcp server of the Ethernet segment. Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your question is pretty neat. I can't get why would anyone downvote it.
So, now you have a setup with two entities: a *router* (say, `192.168.1.1`) connected to the board's *eth0*. So, the *board* acts like a DHCP-client with respect to the *router*. Say, this client is `192.168.1.100` And, as I understand, the board itself is also a DHCP router (say, `10.8.0.1`) which serves a Wi-Fi segment in the corresponding subnet. What happens inside the board is `NAT`, since the two network segments are completely different.

Comment: As far as I understand, you are trying to get rid of Layer-3 (IP) magic within the board and make some sort of like a "wireless switch" or `hub`, kinda Ethernet frames from wireless clients fly to the AP (hostapd), then get decapsulated from wireless headers and get passed untouched to the uplink (eth0) port, so that `eth0` will no longer be the client.

Comment: The clients will be merely the Wi-Fi stations, and their DHCP requests will be passed to the main router (connected to `eth0`), and replies will be forwarded back as well. So, it's a simple Layer-2 switch but one of its ports is wired and the other is an AP. Unfortunately, I've never seen such a setup and neither I've seen some dedicated software for it. But the idea is not bad as it could sound.

Nevertheless, let me ask you, - why do you need such a setup? Well, I can imagine some situations where this will be useful. But why do *you* need your Wi-Fi stations to be in the uplink segment?

Comment: I guess, it smells like a `wireless bridge` or at least very similar.
https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge

Comment: @DaanGerlach thank you for your answers. I need this setup because when I connect a new BBB with its AP to the subnet of eth0 I want to be able to directly reach its wireless clients from my PC (which is connected to the subnet of eth0). It would be also ok not to rely on DHCP and use static addresses for the wlan0 interfaces and the wireless clients. Can you show me a tutorial to achieve this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you're using your little single-board computer as a Wi-Fi AP, and it's currently routing (or probably NAT gatewaying) between wired and wireless, which means wireless is on a different LAN/IP subnet than wired Ethernet. You'd prefer it to just transparently bridge packets between wired and wireless so that everything's on the same LAN and IP subnet.

The way to do this on most Unix-like OSes is to define a software bridge virtual device/interface (it might show up in ifconfig as "bridge0" or "br0" perhaps) and tell your network stack to "attach" both eth0 and wlan0 to the bridge interface. The bridge interface is what then gets an IP address, rather than each physical interface having their own.

Depending on your flavor of Unix-like OS, the exact steps may vary. Also, it's possible to build kernels without the bridging facility, so you might need to ensure that your kernel has it.

NB: Don't get confused by what's often referred to as "wireless bridging" which is a more complicated form of bridging where two boxes use their wireless interfaces to make a point to point wireless link (sometimes called a WDS link) to bridge two wired Ethernet networks together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any tutorial for Debian?

Comment: @ssnape https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections